# RequireJS not working with LockerService

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, locker-service

Problem is pretty straightforward, here is the test code I wrote for this case.

App

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:handler event="c:RequireJSEvent" action="{!c.initJS}"/>
    <aura:registerEvent type="c:RequireJSEvent" name="requireJSEvent"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 
</aura:application>
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        console.log("doinit");
        if (typeof require !== "undefined") {
            var evt = $A.get("e.c:RequireJSEvent");
            evt.fire();
        } else {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script = document.createElement('script');

            script.src = "/resource/RequireJS"; 
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.key = "/resource/RequireJS"; 
            script.helper = this;
            script.id = "script_" + cmp.getGlobalId();
            var hlp = helper;
            script.onload = function scriptLoaded(){
                var evt = $A.get("e.c:RequireJSEvent");
                evt.fire();
            };
            head.appendChild(script);
        }
    },
    initJS : function(component, event, helper){
        require.config({
            paths: {
                "jquery": "/resource/jquery?"
            }
        });
        console.log("RequiresJS has been loaded? "+(require !== "undefined"));
        //loading libraries sequentially
        require(["jquery"], function($) {
            console.log("jQuery has been loaded? "+($ !== "undefined"));
        });//require end
    }
})
```

Console output with LockerService on
[image: LS bug]

Console output without LockerService on
[image: LS not on]

I have a feeling the access check warning might have to do something with this, but I'm not sure..

Answer (score 1):

The access check exception is because your onload callback is not wrapped inside $A.getCallback() so when it gets called the required Lightning context does not get re-established. Access control enforcemernt is not part of LockerService though and this code should fail with or without LS activated.

Try this simople change:

```
script.onload = $A.getCallback(function scriptLoaded(){
   var evt = $A.get("e.c:RequireJSEvent");
   evt.fire();
});
```

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm for more details.

BTW why not just use ltng:require - the native Lightning component that supports dynamic loading, once and only once semantics, is the only Salesforce Security approved mechanism for including JS/CSS, etc? ltng:require also handles both CSS and Javascript resources and already has afterScriptsLoaded event model that is aware of the Lightning component rendering lifecycle, supports $Resource, automatically sets the base URL when running in a Community, and much more.

Comment: Sounds a lot like your last paragraph should be more a statement of best practice than of inquiring.  Is there any valid use to side loading script/css like this with LC?  Is the Security seal of approval an AppEx relevant thing only or will this (using createElement for script/link) eventually be blocked by Locker Service?

Comment: Tried this change, the onload still does not get called. Tried using ltng:require as well, but it still had major issues. For example, I load jquery, then another library that requires jquery to work, and it throws an error saying $ is not defined.

Comment: drakored this is already formally documented. LS will not be blocking dynamic creation of script tags now or in the future though and the security reasons for creating ltng:require go away with LS but the sequencing and timing part is still extremely valuable since no 3rd party loader is LC init/render lifecycle savvy.

Comment: Jason there are a number of variables unaccounted for - can we see the actual example using ltng:require? What version of jQuery etc are you using? Please open a support case and provide the case ID here so we can get a jump on it. There are many successful users of jQuery under LS but some older versions of various libraries have issues.

Comment: @DougChasman I've been unable to successfully include and use RequireJs using ltng:require with LS turned on. I noticed that if I modify Require to set window.require, it is then available on the window and I can reference it in other javascript files.  What is the recommended way to export an API from a module that is loaded through ltng:require?